# Phoning home em arquivo PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf

Olá, boa tarde!
Tenho um trabalho para realizar sobre phoning home, e um dos requisitos é enviar uma notificação que o arquivo foi aberto ou acessado. 
Eu sei que leitores de PDF possuem a função de aceitar comando em javascript (Adober Reader e Foxit, dos que conheço).
Alguém faz ideia de como é possível realizar isso?
Não é preciso dizer que pergunto para fins acadêmicos.

Muito obrigado desde já!

Answer (score -1):

Voce pode criar uma rotina no servidor onde o arquivo está alocado para enviar um email toda a vez que o arquivo for visualisado, no meu caso como a minha especialidade é o desenvolvimento web eu apenas permitiria a abertura de um documento após a execução de um script em php que efetuaria o armazenamento do ip e da data em uma base de dados e enviaria um email avisando ao interessado